# Reset object3d to original position and rotation

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have a gltf model that has an animation that I let the user start/stop by clicking the play button. While I am able to stop the animation from playing when the user hits stop, I am not able to reset the model to it's original position and rotation.

Here is my code

```
 <a-entity gltf-model="#character" texture-map="map: map" position="0 0 -7"></a-entity>
```

and here is the part of the code in the component texture-map that is trying to reset the model back to it's original position of 0, 0 -7

```
  play.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
    if (play.innerHTML === "Stop"){
      play.innerHTML = "Play";
      this.el.pause();
      this.el.removeAttribute("animation-mixer");  
      let position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -7);
      this.el.object3D.position.copy(position); 
      this.el.object3D.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
      this.el.object3D.updateMatrixWorld(); */
      this.el.object3D.lookAt(-3, 0, 0);
    }
    else{
      play.innerHTML="Stop";
      this.el.setAttribute("animation-mixer", "clip", "catwalk");
      this.el.play();                  
    }
})
```

When I execute this code, and hit the stop button, the animation stops but the model's position and the rotation does not get reset. Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what `this.el.pause()` does. What kind of object is `this.el`? Maybe the animation keyframes move the object, and pausing it isn't enough to reset it. You might need to remove the animation altogether.

Comment: this.el refers to the entity that the component (texture-map) is attached to. I am actually removing the animation right after this.el.pause(). this.el.pause() is used to stop a dynamic behavior. I actually removed the this.el.pause() from the code later and it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are controlling the animation using animation-mixer component. 
https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders

Just looking at the api for that, perhaps you could set the loop property to 'once' and time scale to some large neg number, like -100.
In theory, this would make the animation play backwards, very fast, and then stop when finished. I've never tried this, so no idea if it will work, but seems like it could.
Alternately, if you are very brave, you could download the source code for the animation mixer and attempt to create your own property or method that would set the animation frame to the the initial time, or whatever frame you like.

```
 play.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
    if (play.innerHTML === "Stop"){
      play.innerHTML = "Play";
      this.el.setAttribute('animation-mixer',"clip: catwalk; loop: once; duration: .1");
    }
    else{
      play.innerHTML="Stop";
      this.el.removeAttribute("animation-mixer");  
      this.el.setAttribute("animation-mixer", "clip: catwalk; loop: repeat; duration: 15");
    }
  })
```

Comment: you would use `setAttribute('animation-mixer','loop','once')` to set properties

Comment: What a wonderful solution. It worked. I have added the new code to your answer. Thank you so much